# symbols comes twice in opengrok with Project configuration

Tags: opengrok

I am setting up an opengrok with two project with different version (**sudo opengrok-projadm -b /opengrok -a Hello**) and (**sudo opengrok-projadm -b /opengrok -a Hello_v1**)
And index the project individually -

```
sudo opengrok-indexer -a /opengrok/dist/lib/opengrok.jar -- \
    -c /usr/local/bin/ctags \
    -U 'http://localhost:8080/source' \
    -R fresh_config.xml \
    -s /opengrok/src -d /opengrok/data -H -P -S -G \
    -W /opengrok/etc/configuration.xml \
    -H Hello \
    Hello

sudo opengrok-indexer -a /opengrok/dist/lib/opengrok.jar -- \
    -c /usr/local/bin/ctags \
    -U 'http://localhost:8080/source' \
    -R fresh_config.xml \
    -s /opengrok/src -d /opengrok/data -H -P -S -G \
    -W /opengrok/etc/configuration.xml \
    -H Hello_v1 \
    Hello_v1
```

Everything is fine, I am facing only one issue, each symbol  appears twice in search results.

[image]

Any idea why duplicate entries are coming in search results, I am using Release - 1.7.30, and Tomcat 10.

Answer (score 0):

Issue details and resolution can be found at https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/3904